# Find second largest elements in array with duplicates in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Am having array to find second largest elements including repeated value pls find below example.

```
const arr= [1,2,5,5,6]
```

expected result should be

```
[5,5]
```

I tried with map and math.max but i stuck up on logical issue.kindly help me

Comment: Please add your attempt so we can fix it.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: What if the array was [5,5,5,5] ?

Answer (score 3):

Below snippet could help you

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 5, 5, 6]
const max = Math.max(...arr)
const newArr = arr.filter(element => element !== max)
const newMax = Math.max(...newArr)
const secondLargest = arr.filter(element => element === newMax)

console.log(secondLargest)
```

Comment: but will this work for say an array `const arr = [1, 2, 5, 5,7,7,7,6]` ?

Comment: would return `[6]`

Comment: oh yes ....sorry it works fine , mybad .... question here and the requirement is confusing

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler approach, However it may not be the best approach in terms of performance for large data

```js
const ar= [1,2,5,5,6]
secmax = Math.max(...ar.filter((n,i) => Math.max(...ar) !=n ))
res = ar.filter(n =>n == secmax)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: You should point out that there could be performance implications if the array is large enough: we are sorting also parts of the array we are not interested into. But I agree: this is the simpler and cleaner approach.

Comment: @A.Chiesa I have added that, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @A.Chiesa I have fixed the code thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Using a Set to extract unique values shortens the code quite a bit

```js
var arr = [1,5,2,5,4,8];
var uniqueValues = [...new Set(arr)].sort((a, b) => b-a);
var secondHighest = uniqueValues[1]; // 0 is max, 1 is second highest, etc.
var result = arr.filter(x => x === secondHighest);
```

Please keep in mind that there should be some due diligence in accessing the results (what happens if the code is fed with empty arrays, or arrays with a single repeated value? There are many cases not covered here)

Answer (score 1):

You could group the values and sort the array of arrays and get the second array.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 5, 5, 6],
    result = Object
        .values(array.reduce((r, v) => (r[v] = [...(r[v] || []), v], r), {}))
        .sort(([a], [b]) => b - a)
        [1];

console.log(result);
```